# How to update the elements of an integer array index by index

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array like this {0,0,0,0} and I want to update the array from 0 to 1 but one at a time only. 
If i want to update index 0 of the array, the array must be updated from 0 to 1, if the user wants to update again then the index 1 have to be updated from 0 to 1 again in the array.

Do you want to update array? y/n
If y then array must be {1,0,0,0}

Do you want to update again the array must be {1,1,0,0} and goes on like that if the user wish to book seats again. 
My issue when building this program is when I update the array all the elements in the array is updating to 1 at one at a time. I'm using Java for this coding.

```
package ferryassign;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ferryassign {

public static void businessclass_update(int myarray1[][]) // definition of function must be outside
    {
        for(int r=0;r<2;r++)
        {
            for(int c=0;c<5;c++)
            {
                if (myarray1[1][4]==1 && myarray1[10][4]==1)
                    System.out.println("Ferry Full");
                else if(myarray1[r][c]==0) // this one problem 
                    myarray1[r][c]=1;
                else if(myarray1[1][4]==1)
                    System.out.println("Business Class Full");
                    break;

            }
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //main function 
                       //0,1,2,3,4
    int myarray1[][]=  {{0,0,0,0,0}, //0 Business seats
                        {0,0,0,0,0}, //1      
                        {},          //2      
                        {0,0,0,0,0}, //3 Economy seats 
                        {0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0}};

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char ans1;
    do {
            System.out.println("Do you want to buy business seats? y/n");
            char ans=input.next().charAt(0);
            switch(ans)
            {
                case 'y':
                    businessclass_update(myarray1);
                    for(int r=0;r<2;r++) // to print seats use for loop
                    {
                        for(int c=0;c<5;c++)
                        {
                            System.out.println(myarray1[r][c]);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    System.out.println("No business seats selected");
            }
            System.out.println("Do you want to book seats again? y/n");
            ans1=input.next().charAt(0);
        }while(ans1=='y');

    }    
}
```

Comment: "*I want to update the array... one at a time only*" "*My issue... is when I update the array all the elements in the array is updating to 1 at one at a time*". I'm sorry but I'm a little confused about you want this program to do and what it is actually doing. Could you please clarify?

Comment: *FYI:* The `break` statement in `businessclass_update` is incorrectly intended. Since you have no braces on the `else if`, the `break` statement should be unindented one level.

Comment: Example:When I update this array {0,0,0,0} from to 0 to 1, the Output should be {1,0,0,0} and if i want to update the array again it should be {1,1,00} and so on But in my program it is updating all the elements to 1 in the array at a single time. The output is being like this {1,1,1,1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using 2 for loops? Instead use two global variables r and c and increment them each time you call the function and add a seat.

```
  int r=0,c=0;             //r and c are global variables

  public static void businessclass_update(int myarray1[][]) 
  {   

           if (myarray1[1][4]==1 && myarray1[10][4]==1)
               System.out.println("Ferry Full");

            else if(myarray1[r][c]==0) 
                {
                         myarray1[r][c]=1;
                         c++;
                         if(c==5)                //If row is full move to next row
                         {
                             c=0;
                             r++;
                         }
                 }

            else if(myarray1[1][4]==1)
                System.out.println("Business Class Full");

}
```

Comment: thank you. this is Correct it works. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Just take care with the breaks and the brackets:

```
for(int c=0;c<5;c++)
{
    if (myarray1[1][4]==1 && myarray1[10][4]==1)
        System.out.println("Ferry Full");
    else if(myarray1[r][c]==0) { 
        myarray1[r][c]=1; // Since you are iterating it over an array, it will update all the positions 
        break; //With this break you'll do only one time
    }
    else if(myarray1[1][4]==1) {
        System.out.println("Business Class Full");
        break;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Do you want to buy business seats? y/n
y
1
1
0
0
0
1
1
0
0
0
Do you want to book seats again? y/n
y
Do you want to buy business seats? y/n
y
1
1
1
0
0
1
1
1
0
0
Do you want to book seats again? y/n
y
Do you want to buy business seats? y/n
y
1
1
1
1
0
1
1
1
1
0
```

Comment: The output you showed is correct but when I copy the codes the array is not updating if the user wants to book seats again.